# Differential equation of an object movement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have to find the ODE of an object movement with mass $m$ and acceleration $a\neq0$ given
$$x(0)=x'(0)=0$$
and there's a force against the movement
$$F=\alpha\cdot x'$$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R},\alpha\neq0$.

The only answer I can think about is
$$m\cdot x''=\alpha x'$$
but with these initial conditions, I'd have
$$x(t)=0$$
which it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why ! It makes sense indeed. If at $t=0$ the point is at rest with zero velocity the force is $0$ and the object doesn’t move

Comment: @marwalix but since the problem asks for an expression to the position and to the velocity, it's kind weird for me that $x=x'=0$.

Comment: The answer is $x(t) \equiv 0$. It should be a welcomed relief that it is so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force opposes the motion so the correct equation is:
$$
mx''=-\alpha x'
$$
or:
$$
\frac{x''}{x'}=-\frac{\alpha  }{m}
$$
which can be written as:
$$
(\ln x')'=-\frac{\alpha  }{m}
$$
With a 1st integral:
$$x'(t)=x'_0e^{-\frac{\alpha}{m}(t-t_0)}
$$
and a second integral
$$x (t)=x_0+x'_0\frac{m}{\alpha}\big[1-e^{-\frac{\alpha}{m}(t-t_0)}\big]
$$
If there is no motion at $t=t_0$, that is $x'_0=0$, you'll get $x(t)=x_0$